# gcc available, but not installed in fedora

Tags: linux, gcc, fedora, redhat

I installed gcc using `sudo yum install gcc` then I try compile c program it say `gcc command not found` then I try to update the gcc using `sudo yum update gcc` then it say `Page(s) gcc available, but not installed` I try to find an answer in google, but I'm unable to fined the solution. please can anyone help me ?

Comment: Perhaps you should install some particular version of `gcc` i.e. `yum install gcc-4.8`

Answer (score 1):

These steps might help check what the cause could be.

1. `rpm -q gcc` --> check if gcc is installed and managed by yum/rpm
2. `which gcc` --> check if gcc is in your search path for executables
3. `gcc --version` --> check if gcc works in the simplest way (perhaps the error came from incorrect source file path passed to it)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer, first I did `yum update audit` then I install gcc using `yum install gcc` it works fine, thank you for your help